# How to stop quick access from saving encrypted folders?

Tags: anonymity

I use hidden veracrypt drive. It work by saving encrypted drive inside another encrypted drive, so that I can type one password to show fake data and another to show real data. But when I go file explorer, it show frequently used folders in "Quick Access". 
I want to stop veracrypt folder from showing in Quick Access and make sure they are not in any file explorer history at all, how I do that? Will disabling "Quick Access" stop file explorer from saving my history?

I see "clear" option for history. Do I need to clear it every time I use veracrypt? Or should I not give real names to my folder?

Here is image of quick access (from sidebar of file explorer) "Secret folder" is my folder that is appearing that I don't want to appear.

[image: Secret folder is showing]

Answer (score 1):

I found the documentation for this Issue and it basically says, to be save you have to use a hidden Operating system when mounting your volume.

https://veracrypt.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Security%20Requirements%20for%20Hidden%20Volumes